# Sidebar renderiza vários componentes

Tags: angular, router

Tenho um componente dashboard, dentro dele tenho uma sidebar, que tem o efeito de trocar os componentes que serão renderizados na tela, os 4 componentes que podem ser carregados, estão no final da página, mas to com dificuldades para lidar com essa navegação, alguém poderia dar uma ideia de como isso pode ser feito ?

Dashboard:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div style="display: flex; height: 90vh;">
  <div>

    <nav class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" routerLink="/dashboard/funil" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Funil</a>
        <a href="#" routerLink="/dashboard/prospeccoes" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Prospecções</a>
        <a href="#" routerLink="/dashboard/leads-ganhas" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Ganhas</a>
        <a href="#" routerLink="/dashboard/leads-perdidas" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Perdidas</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <app-funil (situationSidebar)="onChangeSidebar()"></app-funil>
  <app-prospeccoes (situationSidebar)="onChangeSidebar()"></app-prospeccoes>
  <app-leads-ganhas (situationSidebar)="onChangeSidebar()"></app-leads-ganhas>
  <app-leads-perdidas (situationSidebar)="onChangeSidebar()"></app-leads-perdidas>
</div>
```

também não sei se o mais ideal seria ter as rotas dessa maneira:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
      { path: 'funil', component: FunilComponent },
      { path: 'prospeccoes', component: ProspeccoesComponent },
      { path: 'leads-ganhas', component: LeadsGanhasComponent },
      { path: 'leads-perdidas', component: LeadsPerdidasComponent },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Não entendi direito. Seu problema é que os 4 componentes estão sendo mostrados no lugar de um especifico dependendo da rota? Pra isso você precisa usar o router-outlet, que dependendo da rota vai mostrar o componente esperado: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: Sou novo no angular, e não tenho muita experiência com as rotas, seria essa a ideia: ao clicar na sidebar, no campo "Funil" por exemplo, exiba o componente "app-funil", ao clicar no Prospecções, exiba o componente "app-prospeccoes" e assim por diante, mas não achei uma maneira de fazer isso ainda, seria ideal trocar esses 4 componentes pelo router-outlet ?

Comment: O router-outlet serve como um "portal" onde vai renderizar naquele local o componente que corresponder com a sua rota, você já declarou corrretamente suas rotas pra carrregar o componente esperado, basta trocar no lugar de <app-funil ... > e os outros componentes um <router-outlet>, ao clicar no menu será carregado dentro do router-outlet o componente que corresponder com sua rota.

Comment: putz, era realmente isso, coisa simples que eu nem imaginava que poderia ser, brigadão kkk ;)